# Eclipse compilation

Tags: eclipse, compilation

How the eclipse decides which file to compile and what not to compile ?

I have a very big project which takes lot of time to get compile , but when i change a single file it some times happen that the whole project starts compiling wasting our valuable time .

Can anyone help in fixing this stuff .

Answer (score 2):

When auto build is enabled, Eclipse tracks which project files have been changed and passes this delta to project builders (Project Properties -> Builders). It is the responsibility of a builder to figure out how much work must happen for a given delta. Some builders (like Java Builder) are very mature and do this well without wasted cycles. Other builders are not as good.

Start by checking which builders you have on the project that is experiencing the described behavior. The next step is more difficult. You need to figure out which builder is responsible for the wasteful building. This isn't easy to figure out without debugging, but you can compare the builders on a project with this problem to builders on a project without this problem. Once you've identified a suspect builder, contact the provider of the plugin in question.